How can I print an uppercase modern xi?
Yeah, basically what the title says. I want to stack two letters Z on top of each other in order to get something like this, and then replace the \Xi command with that (of course, without using FontForge, please).

New Athena Unicode does have something like that, but the image is horrible (and I want the centre stroke to be the same size as the usual, which would mean morfing both Z's from a rectangle enclosure into a trapezium). Here is a couple of (very badly done) versions of how I would expect it to look like:



Welcome to TeX.SE!
